# Boilerplate generator

Tags: backbone.js, generator, yeoman, boilerplate

I'm looking for something similar to yeoman generator for creating boilerplate. But for creating boilerplate inside a existing project. I want to automate a creation of a new view on a large project, which includes the name of the view, and it would create a directories and a javascript for the view, a template, a style for the template, and then declare stuff on some specific file.

e.g. generate `MyView`

would create something like this

```
|-app
|  '--views
|       '-- MyView/MyView.js
|  '--templates
|       '-- MyView/MyView.html
|       '-- MyView/MyView.less
|
|  '--styles.less <- @include templates/MyView.less
|  '--loader.js <- my_view : views/MyView.js
```

Comment: Can't you just make your own generators for yeoman to achieve this? The [backbone generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone#readme) by yeoman already has sub-generators for view, collection etc so it shouldn't be too hard to look at that and the docs and figure it out.

Comment: You can look on http://harmony-boilerplate.com , What I did there is to create templates and a script that get parameters as input from the user and create the structure according to the script and change the code inside the current code, for example : https://github.com/harmony-framework/harmony-boilerplate/tree/master/generator/templates